# Prove that sets being equipotent is an equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ two subsets of $E$. We know that $X$ and $Y$ are equipotent, $X\sim Y$, if there exists a bijective function so that $f:X\rightarrow Y$. Proof that $\sim$ defines an equivalence relation in $\mathcal{P}(E)$.

I don't know how to do that, please help me!

Comment: Have you tried showing if the defining properties of an equivalence relation hold for the given relation?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know how to define the relation

Answer (score 1):

To see reflexivity, observe that the identity map on $X$ is a bijection. To see symmetry, observe that bijections have inverses, so if $X\sim Y$, then there is a bijection $f:X\to Y$, so there is a bijection $f^{-1}:Y\to X$. To see transitivity, observe that the composition of two bijections is a bijection, so if $X\sim Y$ and $Y\sim Z$, then there are bijections $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$, so you have a bijection $g\circ f:X\to Z$ which implies $X\sim Z$.

Comment: Great, thank you Stan!